# Scatterplot with hollow and filled points with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, embedding

I would like to reproduce the scatterplot below. Here is the code I have so far, but I cannot seem to get the points similar to the seed terms to be the same color as the filled points (seed terms). Any help is appreciated.
Also, I cannot figure out why the first word is the color white, even though I used a specific palette?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

seed_terms = ['clean', 'recovery', 'spiral', 'tolerance', 'program']
embeddings_ex = np.random.rand(5, 10, 2)
embeddings_ex = np.array(embeddings_ex)

words_ex = [['quit', 'finally', 'pill', 'vomit', 'survive' ,'lil', 'chance' ,'chain', 'zero',
  'quickly'],
 ['bullshit' ,'unrelated', 'everywhere', 'appear' ,'probably' ,'deal',
  'mistake', 'window', 'comment', 'honest'],
 ['majority' ,'familiar', 'queer', 'edgy', 'skin', 'withdrawl' ,'sad', 'develop',
  'perfectly', 'daughter'],
 ['snort', 'cheap', 'brain', 'teach' ,'shoot' ,'inject' ,'freak', 'type', 'black',
  'absolute'],
 ['substitution', 'suboxone', 'country' ,'clinic', 'nerve', 'representation',
  '2', 'website' ,'youtuber', 'insane']]
words_ex = np.array(words_ex)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9))
sc = embeddings_ex[:, :, 0].flatten()
sw = embeddings_ex[:, :, 1].flatten()
plt.scatter(sc, sw, s=45, marker='o', alpha=0.2, color="none", edgecolors='k')
# annotate(ax, sc, sw, words, size=11)
# fill points that are seed words and make font bold
# Okabe and Ito color palette
colors = ['#FA4D4D', '#FBC93D', '#E37E3B', '#C13BE3', '#4B42FD', '#D55E00', '#CC79A7']

for i, word in enumerate(seed_terms):
    plt.scatter(sc[i], sw[i],  marker='o', alpha=.9,
                color=colors[i], edgecolors='none', s = 100)
    plt.annotate(word, alpha=.5, xy=(sc[i], sw[i]), xytext=(
        5, 2), textcoords='offset points', ha='right', va='bottom', size=11)
# annotate similar words
for word in seed_terms:
    # get the index of the seed word in the list of seed words
    idx = seed_terms.index(word)
    # get the x and y coordinates of the seed word
    x = embeddings_ex[idx, :, 0].flatten()
    y = embeddings_ex[idx, :, 1].flatten()
    # get the list of similar words
    similar_words = words_ex[idx]
    # add annotations with smaller font
    annotate(ax, x, y, similar_words, size=6)

# legend
plt.legend(seed_terms, loc=4)
plt.grid(False)
# remove axes and frame
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
plt.gca().spines['left'].set_visible(False)
# ticks
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', bottom=False,
                left=False, labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)
```

[image]

Comment: in case the image does not show: https://asset.jmir.pub/assets/1bf7be255ec879d659ab01a1f1156fb9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word groups related to the central keyword are taken from the five arrays in a list and are about to be annotated, but since the related word groups are a list, a loop process is required to add scattering and annotation. One thing to be careful of in this method is the order in which the scatter and annotations are drawn. First we need to draw the gray scatter plot, then the scatter and annotations for the related terms, and finally the scatter and annotations for the central terms. The reason is that everything is drawn with the same coordinate data, so the hollow markers will be overwritten after the fill. The attached image controls the overlapping of the annotations, which I assume cannot be achieved with matplotlib alone, so perhaps some other tool is being introduced.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(20230115)
seed_terms = ['clean', 'recovery', 'spiral', 'tolerance', 'program']
embeddings_ex = np.random.rand(5, 10, 2)
embeddings_ex = np.array(embeddings_ex)

words_ex = [['quit', 'finally', 'pill', 'vomit', 'survive' ,'lil', 'chance' ,'chain', 'zero', 'quickly'],
            ['bullshit' ,'unrelated', 'everywhere', 'appear' ,'probably' ,'deal', 'mistake', 'window', 'comment', 'honest'],
            ['majority' ,'familiar', 'queer', 'edgy', 'skin', 'withdrawl' ,'sad', 'develop', 'perfectly', 'daughter'],
            ['snort', 'cheap', 'brain', 'teach' ,'shoot' ,'inject' ,'freak', 'type', 'black', 'absolute'],
            ['substitution', 'suboxone', 'country' ,'clinic', 'nerve', 'representation', '2', 'website' ,'youtuber', 'insane']]
words_ex = np.array(words_ex)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9))
sc = embeddings_ex[:, :, 0].flatten()
sw = embeddings_ex[:, :, 1].flatten()

plt.scatter(sc, sw, s=45, marker='o', alpha=0.2, color="none", edgecolors='k')

# fill points that are seed words and make font bold
# Okabe and Ito color palette
colors = ['#FA4D4D', '#FBC93D', '#E37E3B', '#C13BE3', '#4B42FD', '#D55E00', '#CC79A7']

# annotate similar words
for word in seed_terms:
    # get the index of the seed word in the list of seed words
    idx = seed_terms.index(word)
    # get the x and y coordinates of the seed word
    x = embeddings_ex[idx, :, 0].flatten()
    y = embeddings_ex[idx, :, 1].flatten()
    # get the list of similar words
    similar_words = words_ex[idx]
    # add annotations with smaller font
    for w,xx,yy in zip(similar_words, x,y):
        plt.scatter(xx, yy, s=45, marker='o', color='white', edgecolors=colors[idx])
        plt.annotate(w, xy=(xx, yy), xytext=(5,2), textcoords='offset points', ha='right',va='bottom', size=6)

for i, word in enumerate(seed_terms):
    plt.scatter(sc[i], sw[i],  marker='o', alpha=.9, color=colors[i], edgecolors='none', s=100, label=word)
    plt.annotate(word, alpha=.5, xy=(sc[i], sw[i]), xytext=(5, 2), textcoords='offset points', ha='right', va='bottom', size=11)
    
# legend
plt.legend(loc=4)
plt.grid(False)
# remove axes and frame
plt.gca().spines[:].set_visible(False)

# ticks
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', bottom=False,
                left=False, labelbottom=False, labelleft=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! @r-beginners this was really helpful. I was able to get the annotations also